# Monitor all transactions on bitcoin network - API

Tags: development, api

I am searching for a solution to monitor all bitcoin transactions (or for first ties at least for addresses inside my bitcoin client).

I found http://blockchain.info/api_websocket is this really reliable? What happens if my client is offline?

Is perhaps the better way to run a bc-client an use a poll - every second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with some degree of effort using the Bitcoin API.

v0.7 even has [support for this](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=89725.0) for addresses that are not in your own wallet:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions

There are other tools that you can use to build this capability as well.

- libBitcoin
- Armory (see [Extras](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/tree/master/extras))
- Bitcoin ABE