# How to monitor large number of public addresses

Tags: address, vanity-address

I have created 10K addresses with vanitygen to deal out for transactions, Now how do I watch all those addresses for transactions and balance?

Comment: Import them all into your Bitcoin client?

Comment: @TimS. Can I import public addresses only for watching?

Comment: AFAIK, no. I was suggesting importing the private keys into your client, so that you can see and spend them. You might want to look at this question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4496/12034 (maybe your question's even a duplicate of this)

Answer (score 0):

My idea is create an account at http://blockchain.info/wallet then add all of your address as watch only address. This way you can see everything about them all together or separate.