# How can I read information from the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, development

I don't want to use an existing service, like Blockchain.info or BlockExplorer.com. Is there some library out there that will let me read the blockchain programatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitor all transactions on bitcoin network - API](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4265/monitor-all-transactions-on-bitcoin-network-api)

Comment: Depends a lot on what kind of information you want. Raw blockchain data (such as which block contains which transactions), or derived information which requires indexes and processing (such as how which coins are available to which address).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with some degree of effort using the Bitcoin API.

v0.7 getrawtransaction gives you [access to transactions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=89725.msg990497#msg990497) even those not in your wallet.

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions

There are other tools that you can use to build this capability as well.

- libBitcoin
- Armory (see [Extras](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/tree/master/extras))
- Bitcoin ABE
- BitsOfProof supernode [pre-release]

Comment: The v0.8 client uses LevelDB so I'm not sure that it changes any of the above.  Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

[Gavin Andresen's bitcointools](https://github.com/gavinandresen/bitcointools/) python scripts might have some of the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: From README: "These tools are becoming obsolete as we move away from using Berkeley DB in
Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind."