# Is there a place or tool to monitor all addresses for unmoved coins?

Tags: blockchain, development, tools

I've been looking for a way to easily monitor all address with a balance, that the balance has not moved/changed for a period of time (based on a criteria such as 1 year). Is there a site/tool already available? or do I need to build it myself? if I have to build it, where can I start to look for the relevant data? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read information from the blockchain?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/how-can-i-read-information-from-the-blockchain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In aggregate, this is shown in BitcoinDays Destroyed (e.g., [unspent for one year or more](http://blockchain.info/charts/bitcoin-days-destroyed-min-year)).

This can be done with some degree of effort using the Bitcoin API.

v0.7 getrawtransaction gives you [access to transactions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=89725.msg990497#msg990497) even those not in your wallet.

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions

There are other tools that you can use to build this capability as well.

- libBitcoin
- Armory (see [Extras](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/tree/master/extras))
- Bitcoin ABE

Comment: I'm not sure how to read that BitcoinDays Destroyed chart, or if it is accurate. It fluctuates too much I think, like for the past month, it shows at some point there's only 180k unmoved coins? and there are spikes up to 14M? how to read this chart correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is a no central place or tool yet, but there is a very informative [paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/584.pdf) by [Adi Shamir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shamir) one of the giants of cryptography.