# Preparing a "send" order offline the same way you can create an offline wallet?

Tags: wallet, address, sending, offline

If I have several bitcoins in an offline wallet / cold storage and want to send a few bitcoins to some address, can I somehow prepare and sign the send order offline and only copy the result (say using an USB stick) to an online computer?

For example if I have a wallet with one address which has 1000 coins and want to sent 10 coins to an exchange to sell them, do I need to put my *wallet.dat* to a Bitcoin client which is online? (hence risking to lose it all in case the online computer I'm using is compromised)

Does it changes anything if there's change or not?

It's a theoretical question in order to better understand how bitcoin works.

Comment: Similar or identical to the following question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8101/how-to-sign-a-transaction-using-only-offline-computer