# CLI tool to sign a transaction using a private key in an offline computer

Tags: bitcoin-cli, offline-transactions

## My Problem

Consider an offline computer that has a list of private keys for bitcoin addresses. The computer has some flavor of Linux installed on it, so it can run common CLI tools and Python scripts.

I would like to create a transaction from one of these private keys into a given bitcoin address, sign it, and securely transfer it to an online computer, possibly using a QR code and a phone QR reader that can publish the signed transaction.

## What Have I Tried

- Searching the site, but I only found [old answers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8101/how-to-sign-a-transaction-using-only-an-offline-computer)
- STFW, giving me [non-CLI tools](https://www.cryptocompare.com/wallets/guides/how-to-make-a-bitcoin-offline-transaction/) or obsolete answers
- Playing with [bitcoin-cli](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/) `sendtoaddress`, but it does not seem to support any given private key, just its own wallet.

## My Question

**How can I securely create a signed transaction with a private key, a destination address, and an amount, from an offline computer using CLI tools?**

Comment: I feel like some additional info is required to properly answer this: Is importing the private keys into bitcoind an option? How are you planning to let your offline computer know about the available UTXOs for those addresses?